# Pass by reference vector gives wrong result

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

So I want to create a list of Node by calling constructor and push the address of the Node to a vector (which has been pass by reference). I get the wrong result from the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        //Constructor
        Node(int id, vector<Node*> & listNode){
            this->id = id;
            listNode.push_back(this);
        }
        int id;
};

int main(){
    vector<Node*> listNode;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        Node A(i, listNode);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<listNode[i]->id;
    }
}
```

The output I was expecting is: 01234
But I got 44444 instead.
Any thought about this mistake?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    Node A(i, listNode);
}
```

`A` is scoped to `for` loop, when `for` finishes, `A` was destructed. `listNode` holds a list of dangling pointers.

your code simply has `undefined behavior`.

Enhanced code:

```
class Node{
    public:
        //Constructor
        Node(int id){
            this->id = id;
        }
        int id;
};

vector<Node> listNode;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    listNode.push_back(A(i));
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the Node from being destructed then?

Comment: @jamesalone, this might be a good time to learn about `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @jamesalone you could write `new Node (i, listNode);` instead of `A(i, listNode);`

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle is the cause of the problem.

Your object `A` has been destroyed after a for loop end. (E.g. the obj A created at i=0 will be deleted when i comes to 1)
However, the vector didn't know whether the pointer is unavailable. So the pointer has a value which points to a memory which will never be A's memory.